# Use variable as form fields in Django form template

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-template-filters

```
<here all loading of static , template_filters, crispy_forms >

<form>
{% for i in artifact_length %}
   {% with artifact_name="artifact"|artifact_name:forloop.counter0 %}
        {{form.artifact_name|as_crispy_field}}
   {% endwith %}
{%endfor%}
</form>
```

This is related template code. Here i want to render form fields with names `artifact_0`, `artifact_1` as coming from form. The variable `artifact_name` inside `with` is working fine and returning expected identifiers `artifact_0` , `artifact_1`, but i want to use these variables as form fields to render as `as_crispy_field`.
The code `{{form.artifact_name|as_crispy_field}}` does not print anything because it is assuming form as field with name `artifact_name` which is not. Instead i want to use the value of variable here.

```
forms.py

  class Someform(forms.form):
    def __init__(self, artifact_obj):
        super().__init__()
        count = 0
        for artifact in artifact_obj:
            self.fields[f'artifact_{count}'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput())
                count += 1
```

```
tags.py

@register.filter('artifact_name')
def get_artifact_name(artifact_prefix: str, counter: int):
    print('method', 'prefix', artifact_prefix, 'counter', counter)
    return f'{artifact_prefix}_{counter}'
```

There is variable length form being created. As in`forms.py` form fields are being created with `artifact_count` where count can range from 0 to len of obj.

Comment: Are those the only fields in your form and is `len(artifact_obj)` the same as `artifact_length`?

Comment: there are more fields , i could rander them by name. But these are variable fields and cant estimate how much it will be. Need loop to iterate. . Yes, artifact_length is same as artifact_obj.

Comment: it is being passed in context as `{'artifact_length':range(len(artifact_obj))}`

Comment: What about the order you want to render the other fields in?

Comment: Order does not matter , i just rendered them above all these variable fields. Now need to render these fields too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use filters / template tags, etc. for this purpose. The simplest solution would be to [loop over the form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) to render them:

```
<form>
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
{%endfor%}
</form>
```

This will loop over all the fields in your form.

If you particularly care about the order of these fields you can call the forms [`order_fields` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#notes-on-field-ordering):

```
class Someform(forms.form):
    def __init__(self, artifact_obj, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for count, artifact in enumerate(artifact_obj):
            self.fields[f'artifact_{count}'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput())
        self.order_fields(["field_1", "field_2", ...] + [f"artifact_{i}" for i, _ in enumerate(artifact_obj)] + [..., "field_n"])
```

If you particularly want to render the other fields separately you can add a method to your form that will allow you to loop over these fields:

```
class Someform(forms.form):
    def __init__(self, artifact_obj, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for count, artifact in enumerate(artifact_obj):
            self.fields[f'artifact_{count}'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput())
        self.artifact_length = len(artifact_obj)
    
    def artifact_fields(self):
        return [self[f'artifact_{i}'] for i in range(self.artifact_length)]
```

And then loop over these in the template:

```
<form>
{% for field in form.artifact_fields %}
    {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
{%endfor%}
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I found a workaround by having template tags, filters but that much lengthy. Having addiional method to print artifact is a good idea.

Comment: there is one error now . When i submit the form and did this `if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Someform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():` It throw error now, which i could understand as constructor taking `artifact_obj` and it got `request.POST`. How to resolve this? Do i need to have `args and **kwargs?`

Comment: @JohnByro see my edit, yes you should use `*args, **kwargs`. Also you should pass `artifact_obj` regardless of the request method so `Someform(artifact_obj, request.POST)`

Comment: can you suggest how can we delete the fields dynamically , as we added them in above post.?